# I need generic way to filter IQueryable data and filters are populated as dictionary

Tags: c#-4.0

I need generic way to filter IQueryable data and filters are populated as dictionary. I have already created method like this.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Dictionary<string, string> filterBy)
    {
        foreach (var key in filterBy.Keys)
        {
            source.Where(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(m, null).Equals(filterBy[key]));
        }

        return source.ToList();
    }
```

But its always returning same result.

**please find the caller**

```
            Dictionary<string, string> dtFilter = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dtFilter.Add("Id", "2");
            var res = context.Set<MyEntity>().CustomApplyFilter<MyEntity>(dtFilter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Where extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) does not change the content of the IQueryable it is applied to. The return value of the method should be used:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Dictionary<string, string> filterBy)
    {
        foreach (var key in filterBy.Keys)
        {
            source = source.Where(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(m, null).Equals(filterBy[key]));
        }

        return source.ToList();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I should have noticed it, my answer so far was applicable to LINQ to Objects only. When using LINQ to Entities, however, there are certain restrictions; only expression that can be converted to an SQL query can be used. Getting properties through reflection is not such an expression obviously.

When this is the case, one possible solution would be to build the [ExpressionTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/index) manually.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Dictionary<string, string> filterBy)
{
    foreach (var key in filterBy.Keys)
    {
        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), key);
        var keyPropExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, key);
        var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(keyPropExpr, Expression.Constant(filterBy[key]));

        var condExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eqExpr, paramExpr);
        source = source.Where(condExpr);
    }

    return source.ToList();
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

With the comment @Venkatesh Kumar given below, it is apparent that when the underlying type of the field provided is not of type string, this solution fails (with the error message : The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int64' and 'System.String').

One possible way to tackle this problem would be to have a dictionary of types and delegates to use for each such property.

Since this is a static method (an extension method which has to be static), declaring a static Dictionary  in class scope would be reasonable:

Let's assume the name of the class in which `CustomApplyFilter` is declared is SOFExtensions:

```
internal static class SOFExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> lookup = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();

    static SOFExtensions()
    {
        lookup.Add(typeof(string), x => { return x; });
        lookup.Add(typeof(long), x => { return long.Parse(x); });
        lookup.Add(typeof(int), x => { return int.Parse(x); });
        lookup.Add(typeof(double), x => { return double.Parse(x); });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> CustomApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Dictionary<string, string> filterBy)
    {
        foreach (var key in filterBy.Keys)
        {
            var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), key);
            var keyPropExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, key);

            if (!lookup.ContainsKey(keyPropExpr.Type))
                throw new Exception("Unknown type : " + keyPropExpr.Type.ToString());


            var typeDelegate = lookup[keyPropExpr.Type];
            var constantExp = typeDelegate(filterBy[key]);
            var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(keyPropExpr, Expression.Constant(constantExp));
            var condExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eqExpr, paramExpr);
            source = source.Where(condExpr);
        }

        return source.ToList();
    }
}
```

Other types and proper delegates for them should be added to the `lookup` Dictionary as required.

Comment: Hi Tafa, Thanks for you response

Comment: Its not Working. Showing below exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Hi tafa.. Once again Thanks for you help. I dono aoubt expressions and what it will do.. but its throwing these error npw..  "The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int64' and 'System.String'."

Comment: Well, the error message says it all actually. The underlying type of the field (in the example you provided the Id field) that you are comparing to is of type System.Int64. What the code provides is a string value. (The value "2") since you are using a Dictionary<string, string> the value you are going to get from it is always going to be a string (`filterBy[key]`).

Comment: Hi @Venkatesh. Glad it finally worked out. It would be great if you can mark this answer as the accepted answer.